# Can't set MIME types when using C# HttpListener

Tags: c#, http-headers, mime, httplistener

I created a C# HttpListener().

In the request handler, I perform the needful, then set the headers and MIME type on the response object. However, the browser reported the MIME type was always empty.

```
private void HandleWebRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    string path = context.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLowerInvariant();
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        
    try
    {
        // Respond to requests here. For ex:
        byte[] displayImage = HtmlHelper.GetTextResource(path.Substring(20));
        response.ContentLength64 = displayImage.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(displayImage, 0, displayImage.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        SetResponseHeaders(path, response);
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

---

```
private void SetResponseHeaders(path, response)
{
    ...
    response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I added the headers and and MIME type at the end, when I set Response.Close();

The fix is to set the headers at the beginning

```
private void HandleWebRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    string path = context.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLowerInvariant();
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

    // Set headers here
    SetResponseHeaders(path, response);
        
    try
    {
        // Respond to requests here. For ex:
        byte[] displayImage = HtmlHelper.GetTextResource(path.Substring(20));
        response.ContentLength64 = displayImage.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(displayImage, 0, displayImage.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```